# Google Sheets function output includes special Characters? (<> = "")

Tags: google-sheets

[image: Overview of my problem]

I know a bit of excel and google sheets but I am struggling to find out a few things.
My goal is to have a function that outputs a line of code with a number within that is taken from a different cell.

I have a drop down that allows me to choose a character type.  I have a second cell that checks what character type is selected and finds the corresponding number for said character.  I would then like to take that number and be able to swap it within a line of code for the game.

A1 is the drop down with list of classes

B1 Outputs corresponding number (numbers can range from 0-1000)

C1 uses B1 number to change the game code number

C1 --->  <s16 name="mRomPawnAiNo" value="**964**"/ >

the 964 is what I am trying to change and match from B1

It would also be amazing if the output of C1 showed the whole code.

Things that I have tried (they might still work I was just unable to figure them out) - Replace, Substitute, ToText, Double and Triple quotation marks, using Char(34).    Both figuuring out how to change just the number and displaying the code with its included < >'s ='s and " "'s is causing me problems

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out. I went to far down the rabbit hole and got lost in the weeds.

Answer:

```
="<s16 name=" & """" & "mRomPawnAiNo" & """" &"value=""" & B1  & """" &"/>"
```